# Google maps api kml layer not working

Tags: kml, google-maps-api

The code below was working, but now it is not. This isn't my actual production code, just my KML test document to make sure everything is working. I got this document as a working example from stack exchange.  I saw it working earlier today and yesterday. There is a div at the bottom for the KML status and it even says: OK!.  I hate it when things do not work, but there is not error returned.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">
    </script>

    <script>
    function initialize()
    {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38,-79.5),
        zoom:3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
     }
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOptions);
    var overlay = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://www.dropbox.com/s/zq3st95fbb0kyo4/FireHydrant-small.kml?dl=1');


    overlay.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(overlay,'status_changed',function(){
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = overlay.getStatus();
    });
      }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load', initialize);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="googleMap" style="height:500px;width:600px;"></div>
    <div id="status"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When the code is working, red fire hydrants should appear on the map.